# MS Excel Spreadsheet arrangement

Tags: microsoft-excel

Been given this spreadsheet to make changes if possible.

e.g of the issue:

[image: spreadsheet]

As you can see having it:

```
StudentID StudentName Subject1 Subject2 Subject3
```

would have been better. Is there anyway to convert it to such?

Comment: Build Pivot. Then compress its hard copy to left.

Comment: This can be conclude just like, `ID-----NAME---Physics---MATH---Chemistry----ENGLISH---HISTORY----MARKS--TOTAL--RANK`.

Answer (score 1):

I can see it already in that format in attached pic.
However, if it's not so in your data, use function Transpose function.
You can find Transpose function in right click options.